# Datasource that saves SQL queries in a file, with Java?

Tags: java, sql, datasource, spring-jdbc

I have 2 identical databases and I would like to save all the queries that a Java script runs against the first one (I use Spring Jdbc) in a file that I could run against the second database. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logging proxy driver to log all the statements sent to the first datasource.

One option is [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/). There are other options listed on the bottom of the page. Just configure it to your liking and then use generated logs to feed your second database.